# IE 10 flex, margin-left: auto pushing item out of flex container

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-10

I have a container that will hold:
- A div that has specific width (50px) and floats to the right.
- A button before the above div, that will that the remaining width inside the container.

```
<div class="responsive-button__container">

  <button>Retarded Button</button>

  <div class="awesome-logo"></div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.responsive-button__container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
}

button {
  width: 100%;
}

.awesome-logo {
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

It works fine on Chrome, Safari, and Firefox. But breaks on IE 10 (The div that's supposed to float on the right gets displayed outside of the container)

Codepen: https://codepen.io/d30jeff/pen/GxZPXw

**Edit:** I've decided to use javascript to reduce the button size so the `.awesome-logo` wouldn't get push out of the container at the mean time.

Comment: when dealing with flexbox, use the "flexbox" tag and not "flex" .. flex refer to the poperty and flexbox to the technique

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oops! I'll keep that in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a width of 100% for the button with a flex container. Flex is supposed to manage the width of items by itself. If you do not define a width, but instead allow it to be resized, it should work :

```
button {
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bvpZYa

Comment: Thanks. But the button doesn't take the available empty spaces inside the container.

Comment: It does for me in the codepen I gave. Then again, I can't try with IE10, but IE11 in IE10 mode does give the button filling the container except for the red div on the right.

Answer (score 1):

The default value of **`flex`** has changed: it was `flex: 0 0 auto;` in IE10 (*) but is now `flex: 0 1 auto;` (**).

(*) as stated in the first version of the CSS Flexbox layout spec
(**) in the 3rd and last version of the spec that went to REC (the one implemented in modern browsers)

It's referenced as the [flexbug #6](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-6) (great resource).
Related if you support IE 10: never write flex-basis as 0, always as `flex-basis: 0%;` or `flex: (unitless positive number) (unitless positive number) 0%;`.

⇒ **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/PhilippeVay/pen/WzwBVO)**
EDIT: names of properties and values changed a lot between the different versions of the spec and I didn't use Autoprefixer to "translate" them in my example, meh. Now added on Codepen and in the snippet below:

```css
/* EDIT : Now with an Autoprefixer go-through via Codepen: activated Autoprefixer on Codepen, viewed the compiled CSS and copy-pasted it back in CSS. There now have all the prefixed properties and values for IE10. I guess. */
.responsive-button__container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
}

.responsive-button__container > * {
  /* flex: 0 0 auto; IE 10 default value (none in disguise, in the 1st version of the spec) */
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
          flex: 0 1 auto; /* modern default value (in the spec that went to REC) */
}

button {
  width: 100%;
}

.awesome-logo {
  margin-left: auto;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="responsive-button__container">
  
  <button>Badly displayed button</button>
  
  <div class="awesome-logo"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: The .awesome-logo div is still being displaying outside of the container in IE 10.

Comment: My bad, it needed syntax from the 1st spec and `-ms-` prefixes which are provided by Autoprefixer. I'm so accustomed to my workflow with Gulp that I forget to activate it on Codepen… Does it work now?